# Software package wit its own dynamic library - where to install?

Tags: packaging, shared-library

I have written a piece of software (a `.deb` package) which ships with a dynamic library (`foo.so`) which is only usable to my softare.

Where should I place the library and how can I load it?

I don't think that `/usr/lib` is a good place, because no other softare will ever use the library. Should it reside in for example `/usr/lib/mypackage/foo.so` (that would be my preferred place)? If yes, how would the dynamic linker find the library? Since it is only usable for my software, an entry in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` (which is visible to all other software) is not the first choice. (I use Lua ffi to load the library so I think I can tweak the load path.) Or should I use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If they just few lib's without any concern about naming conflict then avoid creating parent folder to group them.
- Also, it is needed to be put in the correct folder for multi-architecture systems.

Example of `debian/packagename.install` file:

```
usr/lib/lib*.so /usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}
usr/lib/lib*.so.* /usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}
```

*Reference:* [Debian Maintainer Guide - MultiArch](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/advanced.en.html#multiarch)